# Observer throw Exception message without loading logic

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

Observer :

```
public function cartevent(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

        // Load product
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $prodID = $product->getId();
        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prodID);

        // get category id
        $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();

        // check cart
        $cart_qty = (int)Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemQty();

        // check conditiion cart has other products 
        if(in_array(681, $categoryIds) && $cart_qty > 0) {
            Mage::throwException("You can not add This special Product, empty cart before add it");
        }

        // check if other products add to cart
        $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {

            $_product1 = $item->getProduct();
            $categoryIds1 = $_product1->getCategoryIds();
            if(in_array(681, $categoryIds1)) {
                Mage::throwException("If you want Kolu Padi, Purchase alone not mixed with other Products");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

If try to add cart in website, gettin error,

```
a:5:{i:0;s:67:"If you want Kolu Padi, Purchase alone not mixed with other Products";i:1;s:1835:"#0 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/local/Gta/KolupadiRestrict/Model/Observer.php(21): Mage::throwException('If you want Kol...')
#1 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358): Gta_KolupadiRestrict_Model_Observer->cartevent(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#2 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Gta_KolupadiRestrict_Model_Observer), 'cartevent', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#3 /home/abc/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_p...', Array)
#4 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php(290): Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_p...', Array)
#5 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/local/Cmsmart/AjaxCart/controllers/IndexController.php(315): Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->addProduct('5071', Array)
#6 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/local/Cmsmart/AjaxCart/controllers/IndexController.php(133): Cmsmart_AjaxCart_IndexController->tryaddAction(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Array)
#7 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Cmsmart_AjaxCart_IndexController->indexAction()
#8 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#9 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#11 /home/abc/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 /home/abc/public_html/australia/index.php(93): Mage::run('australia', 'website')
#13 {main}";s:3:"url";s:100:"/ajaxcart/index/index/?form_key=MtlJbvKkqPQKCLJR&product=5071&related_product=&qty=1&_=1565155804563";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:9:"australia";}
```

Comment: the obsever is call and error is through from this file

Comment: could you pls explain in brief, i am new in observer, any help to solve the error.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code

```
 public
    function cartevent(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {

    // Load product
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $prodID = $product->getId();
        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prodID);

    // get category id
        $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();

    // check cart
        $cart_qty = (int)Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemQty();

    // check conditiion cart has other products
        if (in_array(681, $categoryIds) && $cart_qty > 0) {

 Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError("You can not add This special Product, empty cart before add it");
                $url = Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer() ? Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer() : Mage::getUrl();
                Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
                Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
                return Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->getRedirect($url);;


        }

    // check if other products add to cart
        $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $prdId = $item->getProductId();
            if ($prdId != $prodID) {
                $_product1 = $item->getProduct();


                $categoryIds1 = $_product1->getCategoryIds();
                if (in_array(681, $categoryIds1)) {

                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError("If you want Kolu Padi, Purchase alone not mixed with other Products");
                    $url = Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer() ? Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer() : Mage::getUrl();
                    Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
                    Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
                    return Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->getRedirect($url);;

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Working partially, one condition working, like if cart has restricted category of products observer not allow add other category of products to cart, but another condition if cart has other category of products don't allow restricted category of products not working.

Comment: you need to set the logic for that in your own way, ill give you the solution for the error occur.

Comment: i add one new condition in your logic if ($prdId != $prodID) { you can remove that if or comment that and check

Comment: if you get the solution than please accept and up vote my answer

Comment: Still getting error, 503 Service Unavailable

Comment: you need to set the logic as per your need

Comment: I just have small doubt, if this is return products category id - > https://justpaste.it/7p95f ?

Comment: yes it return the category array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97146/discussion-between-zus-and-jigs-parmar).